# How to make a multi vector in C++

Tags: c++

I was wondering why can't I have a multi vectors in C ++ /please take a look at this example, it's not working though.

there are only two parts to the code,  foo function to manipulate the vector and the main function to echo them.

```
typedef vector< vector<double> > MyVec;

MyVec foo() {
    MyVec v;    

    for (int index=0; index < 2; index ++) {
        for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {
            v[index][j];
        }   
    }

    return v;
}

int main () {
    MyVec z = foo();

    for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); i++) {
        cout << z[i][1];                    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "it's not working". seriously?

Comment: @oli chareleworth, this pretty much your example I got from a pervious answer about an hour ago. I am just trying to have a multidimensional vector

Comment: @Ash, just trying to create a multidimensional vector in a function and echo it back into the main function .

Answer (score 2):

You're accessing elements that don't exist. You need to construct the vectors beforehand.

Assuming the dimensions of your vector are `v[2][5]`, replace the declaration in `foo()` from `MyVec v;` to `MyVec v(2, vector<double>(5, 0));`

This is basically constructing v to contain 2 vector elements, and those 2 vector elements are in turn being constructed to contain 5 elements initialised at 0.

You can then remove the nested for-loop altogether.

To be quite honest, all you really need is this:

```
typedef vector< vector<double> > MyVec;

int main () {
    MyVec z(2, vector<double>(5, 0));

    for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); i++) {
        cout << z[i][1];                    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A vector doesn't have any elements when it's first created.  So you can't do something like this:

```
std::vector<double> vec;
vec[1] = 42.0;
```

because you'd be trying to write to an element that doesn't exist.

If you want a 2D vector of a known size, one option is to specify the size:

```
MyVec v(NUM_ROWS);
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
    v[i].resize(NUM_COLS);
}
```